# Find MINIMUM in multiple-column range, return value from Column A

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, textjoin

I am working on a spreadsheet for my fantasy football draft. Screenshot below.

I'm looking to put a formula into **AA25** that finds the *MINIMUM VALUE* of **W1:AH17** and then returns the corresponding value in **Column A** in the same row.

For example, in the screenshot, the minimum value in W1:AH17 would '12' (*cell AH1*), which would then return the value '1' (*cell A1)*.

I currently have a successful formula in AA25...

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF((MIN(W22:AH22))=(W1:AH17),(A1:A17),"")))
```

...that returns the value I'm looking for, except it's using TEXTJOIN to do so. So when I pull that number into another sheet, it isn't being recognized as a numeric value, but instead text.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF((MIN(W22:AH22))=(W1:AH17),(A1:A17),""))*1)
```

By using `*1` or `+0` we turn the text value of the number to a real number.

Comment: Perfect! Amazing how simple that solution is, thank you! (Making me wait a few minutes before accepting this answer as correct, but will do)

Comment: @sebo620 I would also suggest if I may (since this is not tight to MINIMUM) to maybe changing the title to something more general like *"turning a number value to a number"*